# Password Policy Setting for a Website in c# 2008

Tags: c#, passwords

I have a web application in `c# 2008`.

I'm assigned a task to set the password policy for this web site.

The policy is

- The 1st character is Upper Case
- The 2nd character is lower case
- The Character is a "special character"
- The 4th through 8th character are random digits
- The password is exactly 8 characters
- The password should expire after 6 months

I'm not able to figure out this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it "right" and correct, go for Regular Expressions. If you don't have any experience with them, forget it if it's urgent.

Instead go with the quick and dirty way. This is untested pseudo-code:

```
if (password.Length == 8)
{
   check password[0] for upper case
   check password[1] for lower case
   check password[2] for special char
   check password[3] && password[7] for "random digits"
   //return false, throw error, whatever you want in the case of any failures.
}
else
{
   return error "your password is too short"
}
```

Not sure what you  want to do for making the password expire in 6 months. If you are treating your password as a custom class with an "expiration date" field, and you just want 6 months from now, just use MyPassword.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6);

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good practice to ask it in here without trying anything. It sounds like you are trying to make your job done by others. I can suggest the way you should do instead of providing code.

You can do it by using regular expressions. You can search for it . There are many resources.You should constuct a regular expression that will check for the constraints you want except the password expiration. You should check password expiration on your database. You can define a job that will work every midnight , which will check the password database and detect the passwords that expires.

Comment: I tried the available  regular expressions... but they dont seem to work for my requirement.. Sorry for inconvenience for not being specific... The regular expression doesnt seem to solve my purpose. as i have fixed policy as in 1st char is caps and 2nd lower 3rd has to be a spl char... the regular expressions check for random availability of the chars in string and not the order... this is the issue actually

Comment: you sure that you searched for it ? Just a 2 seconds search on google brought me this result : http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=79